# Jquery replace string

Tags: javascript, jquery

May sound like a total noob question but i'm looking for a javascript (and or jquery) function to replace an element in this code :

```
<embed id="ply" width="800" height="400" 
 flashvars="file=http://example.com/play/"
 allowscriptaccess="always" 
 allowfullscreen="true" 
 quality="high" bgcolor="#00000" 
 name="ply" style="" 
 src="/video-player.swf" 
 type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

I want to be able to replace the :

```
flashvars="file=http://example.com/play/"
```

and append some text (for video seeking) :

```
flashvars="file=http://example.com/play/234983"
```

Must be really easy to do, but i'd appreciate help for some more experienced user.

Comment: Do you realize changing the attribute string will not automatically reload the video with your new url?

Comment: Mmmh you're right, how can I force the player to reload ?

Comment: you could modify it as I gave an example below, but remove and then reappend it.

Comment: Not sure to understand, can you give an example ?

Comment: i expanded my original answer. hopefully that will clarify what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#ply").attr("flashvars", $("#ply").attr("flashvars") + "/234983");
```

---

**Update**
If you want to reload the player, this may work. It will clone the existing embed tag with the ID `ply`, only replacing the `flashvars` attribute value. This effectively removes `ply` from the DOM and then inserts it in place again. This would hopefully cause the browser to reload the player.

```
var p = $("#ply");
p.replaceWith(p.clone().attr("flashvars", p.attr("flashvars") + "/234983"));
```